# C-level function for returning invisibly in R?

Tags: r

Is there a C-level function (from R' C API) for returning invisibly in R?

I know there is `invisible()` that can be called from R code. But I was wondering if something analogous exists at C-level.

Comment: There's no API function for that.  You could presumably call `invisible()` from within your C code (by constructing an expression and evaluating it), but since all user code needs to go through an R function to get to C, why not just call `invisible()` at the R level?

Comment: I am thinking that if I want to run a function implemented at C level, for its side effects, let us say, to print to console, it would be nice to not return `NULL` visibly and hence avoid the extra visual noise.

Comment: Can I call primitive functions at C level? Given that `invisible()` is a `.Primitive`...

Comment: To tell you my motivation: I am actually including compiled C functions with `inline:cfunction()` in the examples' section of Rd files  and I would like to transfer the visual clutter of `invisible()` wrappings to the inside of the compiled code. But if that is not possible, that's fine. Feel free to reply with a proper answer and I will be happy to deem it the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could presumably call `invisible()` from within your C code (by constructing an expression and evaluating it), but since all user code needs to go through an R function to get to C, why not just call `invisible()` at the R level, e.g.

```
myFun <- function(...) {
   invisible(.Call(...))
}
```

In reply to some comments:  most functions used within R (including all the C functions corresponding to `.Primitive`s, as far as I know) are not part of the API and shouldn't be called from your code.  It's only safe to call the documented functions from the Writing R Extensions manual.

A few packages go beyond the API functions because of a need for functionality that isn't there.  This will probably make your package ineligible for CRAN unless you can convince CRAN that you've got a very good reason for doing it, and that you'll respond rapidly to any changes to the undocumented internal.